# Bootstrap - Disable body scroll on full screen implementation of Collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the XS breakpoint, the div I am using Bootstrap's collapse feature on is full screen and has enough content that it requires a scroll. I want to disable the rest of the website from scrolling when this is expanded. I have tried overflow:auto on the div and overflow: hidden on the body but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is this possible to have scrolling enabled on the div when its expanded and have the body scrolling disabled?

Edit: Figured it out. Thanks to everyone that jumped in to help!

Comment: Could you post some sample code please

Comment: Could you provide some sample code with the issue that you're describing? https://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: @Quiver please do not suggest external sources for the code. The code should be *in the question itself*

Comment: @CalvT I wasn't suggesting for him to only include the code as an external source but merely so that we could have a live example as suggested in the guidelines of SO: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: Welp, I got it figured out. Either way, I appreciate the willingness to help. Thank you so much.